# show google maps in android v2 app crashes on open activity, inflate exception binary file number #2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to open google maps to show some locations. I am following http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/ link for this, but its not opening maps its crashing and says  inflate exception  binary file number #2, i have checked in manifest meta data is fine, fragment is case sensitive, key is correct , here it is my stack trace :

```
 02-26 18:15:25.648: I/System.out(5029): img button cust.>> 02-26
 18:15:25.718: D/AndroidRuntime(5029): Shutting down VM 02-26
 18:15:25.718: W/dalvikvm(5029): threadid=1: thread exiting with
 uncaught exception (group=0x40a191f8) 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
activity
 ComponentInfo{com.intertec.iforce/com.intertec.iforce.MapActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
 inflating class fragment 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):
    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 com.intertec.iforce.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:23) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    ... 11 more 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029): Caused by:
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
 instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment:
 make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor
 that is public 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):     at
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    ... 20 more 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029): Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment 02-26 18:15:25.758:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
 02-26 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):    at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  at
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391) 02-26
 18:15:25.758: E/AndroidRuntime(5029):  ... 23 more 02-26 18:15:25.838:
 D/dalvikvm(5029): GC_CONCURRENT freed 326K, 20% free 6795K/8391K,
 paused 2ms+2ms 02-26 18:20:25.808: I/Process(5029): Sending signal.
 PID: 5029 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you imported google play services lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you have missed to import the project from `\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`.

Add it as `library` to your current project.

Make sure you have used `SupportMapFragment` for API under 11.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: yes you are right, that was the problem. thank you so much :) now its working fine, but its showing whole map of earth, can i get exact route from current location to a given location(hardcode the latitude and longitude). now it is the problem.

Comment: Hence its not related to the current location, i suggest you to post another question. It's possible to achieve..

Comment: mitesh, i have asked the question, if u can help me then i will be highly obliged. this is the link for question. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090351/in-android-google-maps-api-v2-for-4-0-show-the-routes-from-current-location-to