# in Android google maps api v2 for 4.0, show the routes from current location to given lat long

Tags: android, routes, google-maps-android-api-2

For android in google maps api v2 its showing whole earth by following all the steps from here http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/ , can i zoom in the route from current location to given lattitude and longitude, and the problem is i need to show multiple routes, how is it achievable?? right now i am not doing anything in my activity, but i think i have to do some coding for drawing the routes. how can i do this? thank you so much for your answers, and please provide me any tutorial if u know. thanks again.

Comment: Follow this awesome [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/)

Comment: thank u mitesh , i will look into it. seems it has the exact answer im looking for.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem by using this code.. : try this class :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GMapV2Direction {
    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public GMapV2Direction() { }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

you can get sample code here

```
LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);

GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();

Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
}

mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

:- https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0MdROeR0jbvWVVNUV9jbk1OeEE

Comment: we need xml document response to draw a route.. this code is all about that.

Comment: It's better to add content instead of link.. Currently link is not working.

Comment: Download link is not working anymore. Please update it.

Answer (score 0):

Android maps api V2 have `Polyline` class to draw the route on a map.

```
Polyline line1 = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(50.5, 34.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
 .width(5)
 .color(0xFFFF0000));
```

Comment: hey Mitesh, thank you for your answer i will use it later, but i am using that similar tutorial, from this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/ but still its not effecting any thing showing only full google map, now current location, im trying this from last half an hour, no errors are coming, nothing special happening on stack trace,

Comment: are you getting current location button on map?

Comment: No buttons are defined on xml layout, thats why i am not getting any button, in this link they are showing to get current location directly i think.

Comment: Need to set `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` to show current location

Comment: yes its already there, , i debugged the code, and its not calling onLocationChanged() method, i think in this method only they are focusing camera, please correct me .

Comment: Got the problem... locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); method is returning null, not location. but whats the solution?

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) for getting location

Comment: Hi mitesh, mow am able to get the current location, and I am using your polyline code , but  that just create a straight line for two Latlongs, as I told you i need proper routes. can u please help me on this?

Comment: sloved it.. interested fellow. see my answer for solution