# I get force close when i run google maps v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I have a problem with Google map v2 i am following this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api 
But i get error message like this

```
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.easytaxi/com.example.easytaxi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.example.easytaxi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    ... 11 more
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.easytaxi-1.apk]
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-22 22:24:07.476: E/AndroidRuntime(19690):    ... 19 more`enter code here`
```

this is my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.easytaxi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.easytaxi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.easytaxi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.easytaxi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="My API Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my activity_main.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

also i'm running it on my phone not on emulator and i have already installed google play service so i don't know where i'm making a mistake.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am no Android dev, but it looks like you are missing a class in your classpath: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Comment: Please refer my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089772/1278196)

Comment: Before the problem was Google Play Service after installing it this problem appeared also i'm just following this [link](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) and doing what it does

Comment: I have imported \extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib and changed MapFragment to SupportMapFragment.My phone's android version is 2.3.6.I have also changed target version to  11 again I get force close

Comment: @user1833334 Now what error you getting?

Comment: Again the same error what i showed above i don't know where i'm making a mistake

Comment: Make it like this: public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: @user1833334 have you added the support library??

Answer (score 1):

t looks you have missed to import the project from `\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib.`

Add it as `library` to your current project.

Make sure you have used `SupportMapFragment` for API below 11.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Now i get an error message that install the latest version of ADT